# Configuring intersection table in EF Core 2.1.1

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I have a pretty simple need, but I can't figure out how to do it with EF core 2.1.1 in code first.

I have a table `Right` and a table `Role`:

```
Role
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

Right  
public int RightId { get; set; }  
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Usually, in a standard database, I would simply make an intersection table `Named`:

```
RoleRights(RoleId int, RightId int)
```

But it seems in ef core 2.1.1, you instead add navigation properties.

```
Role
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Right> Rights { get; set; } 

Right
public int RightId { get; set; }  
public string Name { get; set; } 
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

A `Role` can contain any number of `Right` and a `Right` can be contained in any number of `Role`.

By doing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(r => r.Rights);
modelBuilder.Entity<Right>().HasMany(r => r.Roles);
```

It flattens my `Role` table and add a `RightId` instead of making an intersection table. Same thing for the `Right` table. It adds a `RoleId`.

In the `Migration` script:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "RightId",
    table: "Roles",
    nullable: true);

migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "RoleId",
    table: "Rights",
    nullable: true);
    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Rights_Roles_RoleId",
        table: "Rights",
        column: "RoleId",
        principalTable: "Roles",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Roles_Rights_RightId",
        table: "Roles",
        column: "RightId",
        principalTable: "Rights",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

How can I configure my model to have an intersection table instead? In this case, it is generating a wrong schema. I cannot insert and empty `Role` or a `Right` in no `Role`. Thinking of it, I should probably never do that anyway, but it feels wierd to me.

Thanks for your time!

If anything is not clear, tell me what needs more detail and I'll clarify!

Comment: "But it seems in ef core 2.1.1, you instead add navigation properties" Where did you read that?

Comment: Like this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Comment: That's not what you did. For one, you shouldn't use `IEnumerable`, and the collections should contain `RoleRight`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had followed something outdated. The solution is to explicitly make the join table.

```
   public class RoleRight : IEntity
   {
      public int RoleId { get; set; }
      public Role Role { get; set; }

      public int RightId { get; set; }
      public Right Right { get; set; }
   }
```

With both Right and Role looking like this.

```
   public class Right : IEntity
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public virtual List<RoleRight> RoleRights { get; set; }
   }
```

With this configuration on the OnModelCreating

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<RoleRight>().HasKey(rr=> new { rr.RightId, rr.RoleId });
 modelBuilder.Entity<RoleRight>().HasOne(rr => rr.Right)
                                 .WithMany(r => r.RoleRights)
                                 .HasForeignKey(rr => rr.RightId);

 modelBuilder.Entity<RoleRight>().HasOne(rr => rr.Role)
                                 .WithMany(r => r.RoleRights)
                                 .HasForeignKey(rr => rr.RoleId);
```

Which is basically the last section in the link I provided in the comment earlier.
I have no clue how I had missed it when I read the page the first time!